# Bootstrap 3, menu nav-pills

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap

Как сделать выделение активного (нажатого) раздела/ссылки в меню?
Какой нужно добавить JS из Bootstrap и что нужно добавить в само меню?

Код:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<ul class="nav nav-pills">
  <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
</ul>
```

Пример меню: [changeip.ru](http://www.changeip.ru)

Comment: Выделение происходит за счёт добавления класса "active", но сам по себе этот класс бутстрап не добавляет. Это уже вы должны на стороне движка/сервера добавлять класс элементу меню, соответствующему текущей странице. По клику добавляется класс например "open", но он для выпадающий dropdown list.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы переместить класс Актив на другой элемент, Вам нужно написать примерно такой код на JavaScript:

```
$(function($){

var location = window.location.toString();

switch(location ){

    case "/home": 
        $('.НазваниеКлассаВашегоМеню li).removeClass('active');
        $('.НазваниеКлассаВашегоМеню li[href="/home"]').addClass('active'); brake;

    case "/page1": 
        $('.НазваниеКлассаВашегоМеню li).removeClass('active');
        $('.НазваниеКлассаВашегоМеню li[href="/page1"]').addClass('active'); brake;
    ....

    }
});
```